# How to use conditional columns values in the same select statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, case, conditional-statements

I have something like

(`COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_N` stands for a long subquery)

```
select
  ID_Operation,
  FirstCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  SecondCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  ThirdCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_3)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  AllChecksOk = Case WHEN 
               (FirstCheck + SecondCheck + Third CHeck = 3) 
               Then 'OK' Else 'No' End
from 
  AllOperationsTable
```

Is it possible to use FirstCheck, SecondCheck, ThirdCheck as I did in the AllChecksOk line?

I am not concerned about performance, this is something that is manually run once a day on a very small number of records, I just want to avoid to create views, tables or temporary tables and keep all in a single select statement.

As an altenrative I can do this, but it makes the query less readable (as I need to write twice every complex expression):

```
select
  ID_Operation,
  FirstCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  SecondCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  ThirdCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_3)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  AllChecksOk = Case WHEN 
               (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1+ COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2+ 
               COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_3CHeck = 3) Then 'OK' Else 'No' End
from 
  AllOperationsTable
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't reference a column alias in the `select` but you can use a CTE as below.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
select
  ID_Operation,
  FirstCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  SecondCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2)= 0 then 0 else 1 end,
  ThirdCheck = CASE WHEN (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_3)= 0 then 0 else 1 end
from 
  AllOperationsTable
)
SELECT *,
       AllChecksOk = Case WHEN 
               (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1+ COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2+ 
               COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_3CHeck = 3) Then 'OK' Else 'No' End
FROM CTE
```

You can also use `CROSS APPLY` to define the 3 column aliases then reference them in the main `SELECT` list [as in this example](http://www.sqlmag.com/blogs/puzzled-by-t-sql/entryid/72321/tip-apply-and-reuse-of-column-aliases).

Comment: CTE did the job, i didn't look to CROSS APPLY, I'll bookmark it for the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a derived table solution

```
SELECT
  T.ID_Operation,
  FirstCheck   = CASE WHEN T.Expr1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  SecondCheck  = CASE WHEN T.Expr2 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  ThirdCheck   = CASE WHEN T.Expr3 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
  AllChecksOk  = CASE WHEN T.Expr1 + T.Expr2 + T.Expr3 = 3 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'No' END
FROM
(
  SELECT
    ID_Operation,
    Expr1 = (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1),
    Expr2 = (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_2),
    Expr3 = (COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_3)
  FROM 
    AllOperationsTable
) T
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find using CTE or derived tables a bit confusing for this purpose, as you have to nest things one level and think about the nesting impliciations. A much simpler approach (at least in my opinion) is to use `APPLY` (or standard SQL `LATERAL` in other RDBMS) to generate column expression aliases:

```sql
SELECT
  ID_Operation,
  FirstCheck,
  SecondCheck,
  ThirdCheck,
  AllChecksOk = CASE
    WHEN FirstCheck + SecondCheck + ThirdCheck = 3 THEN 'OK' ELSE 'NO'
  END
FROM
  AllOperationsTable
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      FirstCheck = CASE WHEN COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
      SecondCheck = CASE WHEN COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
      ThirdCheck = CASE WHEN COMPLEX_EXPRESSION_1 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
  ) t
```